# committing a bunch of files in git with one command vs multiple commands

Tags: git

In svn you'd do this:

```
svn ci -m "..." filename1.ext filename2.ext
```

In git you'd do this:

```
git add filename1.ext
git add filename2.ext
git commit -m "..."
```

Personally, I prefer the git method but I am curious none-the-less...  can you mention all the individual files you want to commit in the commit command itself as you can with SVN?

Comment: yes you dont need to add them all first either just git commit file1 file2

Answer (score 1):

This *does* work:

```
git commit -m "..." filename1.ext filename2.ext
```

On the condition that the files have already been `git add`-ed before, and now they have some modifications. But that condition is true with `svn` too. You can only commit changes to files that were already added, in a previous revision for example.

Of course, `git add` works differently from `svn add`, as it has the much more sophisticated staging area feature. But in terms of committing pending modifications, the `git commit` above works just like `svn ci`. (At first I wrote `git ci`, which doesn't exist, it's an alias I always use. And personally this is how I commit pending changes most of the time, I select the files directly, much like you are used to with Subversion.)

Comment: But `svn add` means something different to `git add`.

Comment: Yes, I added clarification for that.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, `git add` supports the `-A` flag which will add all previously unadded files (usually files that are newly created).

```
git add -A
git commit -m "my commit message here"
git push
```